# Mysql php get record where number is between two ranges

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table named 'prices' and every range has its price.

```
course_id start  end    price 
-----------------------------
1          1      5     20
1          5      10    18
1          10     100   15
-------------------------
```

I have for example `$course_id = 1` and `$weeks_num = 8`.

How can I get the price of that course?

In the given example I should have 18 because 8 exists between 5 and 10.

Comment: Oh , come on. Try something.

Comment: Or as it is more often politely said this is a site to get help on code issues not to be given solutions Please show us the code you have and explain where your issue is.

Comment: To add to the previous comments, even if you are not sure how to write the code, you can try to write some pseudo code, and then we can help you. But this is a very basic question you're asking, I'm sure you can solve it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `BETWEEN` clause. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

```
...
WHERE 8 BETWEEN start AND end
...
```

Comment: ... or as a SQL statement:

    [...] WHERE $weeks_num BETWEEN start AND end;